# Authentication using React and Pyramid (microservices architecture), how to store "session data"?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, architecture, jwt, pyramid

How are you?
Me..? Well, I'm having some trouble, haha!

I'm using a microservices API architecture on a project where the APIs and GatewayAPI is developed with Python's Pyramid framework, and the main frontend is built with React.
Simple workflow ilustration: https://i.stack.imgur.com/box3c.jpg

**The problem is:** where do I safely store the authenticated "session data", like username, user_id, first_name? After logging in, I don't want to make new requests to the user's API just to get these information that will be constantly used.

I know I can store this coded data in the `JWT token` and store the token in the `cookies` or the `localStorage`, but is this the right place? And is this the right process?
If this is the right place, do I need, everytime, to send the decoded data to the frontend as part of the GatewayAPI response?

Thank you for the reading and I hope you guys can save me!

Comment: Can't you just save in session? e.g, like 'session=request.session' and save in session like 'session['something'] =something'. Session can be stored in cookies or by server side using redis. Just make sure the authentication timeout is in sync with the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the JWT in a cookie or localStorage it does not matter. I personally do so in localStorage.

Regarding your question about decoding the data, this is handled by the backend. All you need to do is include the JWT in every API call and the API will know which user is calling without the need to send the data back and fort.

I would also recommend you create tokens with an expiration date for added security.

For examples you can take a look at [pyramid_jwt](https://github.com/wichert/pyramid_jwt)

Comment: Thank you very much!

We decided to use Flask instead Pyramid, but we did I like you said!
Added  the JWT to the localStorage, and the data decode is done by the backend.